# How to check if the values of vectors is decreasing

Tags: r

I am working on a function where the values at each iteration MUST be increasing. To check that, I returned the values as a vector. The elements of this vectors may be more than `100`, depends on the iterations of the model. I would like to check if the values of the elements keep increasing or there are some values that are decreasing. Checking each element is very hard. So, I tried to do that automatically using a function in R. I really do not know how to fix this.

For example,

Here, I have 2 vectors. The values of `xx` are increasing, while there is one element that decreasing in `yy`.

```
 xx <- c(-2.0802226,4.3585333,  7.4683596,  9.3433614, 10.6003443, 11.0068023, 
         11.1151467, 11.1667744, 11.1950104)

 yy <- c(-2.0802226,4.3585333,  7.4683596,  9.3433614, 10.6003443, 11.0068023, 
         10.1151467, 11.1667744, 11.1950104)
```

I would like to check automatically if there is decreasing in my vector.

Comment: another option: `identical(xx, sort(xx)); identical(yy, sort(yy))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can differentiate and test If all are positive, i.e.

```
is_increasing <- function(vec) {
    return(all(diff(vec) > 0))
}

is_increasing(xx)
#[1] TRUE
is_increasing(yy)
#[1] FALSE
```